# SQL Server - Orders By Client with 1 minute difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 3 columns

```
ClientId | OrderId | CreatedDate  
1 | 1 | 2015-10-27 10:00:00  
1 | 2 | 2015-10-27 10:00:30  
2 | 3 | 2015-10-27 10:30:30  
3 | 4 | 2015-10-27 10:35:00  
3 | 5 | 2015-10-27 10:35:45  
3 | 6 | 2015-10-27 12:30:00
```

I want to count the number of orders from the same client inserted (more or less) in the same minute.

This way my expected result would be

```
ClientId | Count(OrderId)  
1 | 2  
2 | 1  
3 | 2  
3 | 1
```

I've tried using a inner join with itself but wasn't able to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want the difference between two orders for a client?  You simply join the table to itself using an alias.

Comment: Maybe i haven't explained right... i want to count the number of order from the same client inserted (more or less) in the same minute. should be something like `po2.Created BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, - 1, po1.Created) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, po1.Created)`

Comment: You need to add that to your question, your question currently does not make any sense, hence the wrong answers being posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyOrders
(
    ClientId Int,
    OrderId Int,
    CreatedDate DateTime
)


INSERT INTO #MyOrders
VALUES
    (1,1,'2015-10-27 10:00:00'),
    (1,2,'2015-10-27 10:00:30'),
    (2,3,'2015-10-27 10:30:30'),
    (3,4,'2015-10-27 10:35:00'),
    (3,5,'2015-10-27 10:35:45'),
    (3,6,'2015-10-27 12:30:00')

SELECT  ClientId, Count(*) as [Count(OrderId)]
FROM #MyOrders
GROUP BY ClientId, DATEADD(Minute, DATEDIFF(Minute, 0, CreatedDate), 0)
```

This gives

```
ClientId    Count(OrderId)
--------    --------------
1           2
2           1
3           2
3           1
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ClientId,count(1)
from yourtable
group by ClientId,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(17),CreatedDate,113) AS datetime)
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0486/2)

Comment: This does not handle the minute interval you'll get counts for everything.  In his sample above clientid = 3 should only have 1 count.

Comment: @JonH - But I can see the same result as expected by OP

Comment: you are right my appologies the question was edited...sorry

Comment: Sorry for not being completely clear when creating the question. As edited what I want is to count the number of orders from the same client inserted (more or less) in the same minute.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select clientid, count(*)
from table
group by cast(createddate as date), datepart(hour, createddate), datepart(minute, createddate)
```

Comment: You don't need to group by the last part, a simple where condition would get rid of the records you don't need.

Comment: @JonH, cant get what you mean

Comment: The last grouping is unnecessary as long as you don't give back orders within the threshold he has asked.  Check his question.

Comment: @JonH, are you sure? This select will produce exactly what is in the question.